Remove Pending Queries in Power BI
I am using Power BI
i tried to connect to a SP and did not work for several times.
at the end i find another way and worked
now everytime i try to save my Power BI dashboard I get this message


I disgarded these messaages so many times and is still showing.
how can remove these queries?
